# Using AWK to break out pieces of a single file into multiple files, but I need further direction

Tags: awk, split

I am still very new to this type of task, but I have exhausted my resources and thus am reaching out for a helping hand.

I have a single file composed of concatenated files. I am able to use the exact line of code below to break the files apart:

`awk "/PATTERN/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}" sourceFile`

BUT -

1. If possible I would like to dictate a directory for the output files - the above script writes the output files to the "sourceFile" directory, I would want these files to be dropped in some sort of temp directory.
2. It would be extremely helpful if the output files could retain their
   "sourceFile" name with perhaps a counter on the end while
   maintaining a .txt file type - i.e. sourceFile1.txt,
   sourceFile2.txt, etc.

I have tried the following to retain the sourceFile name, but it was unsuccessful:

```
set F=sourceFile
awk "/PATTERN/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}" sourceFile
```

I apologize if this is rudimentary, but this could greatly aid in daily tasks - so I was hoping someone could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK split files into smaller files on pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472425/awk-split-files-into-smaller-files-on-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much there just prefix the filename with the directory and append the file extension using string concatenation:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{file="tmp/"(FILENAME)(++i)".txt"}{print > file}' sourceFile
```

We don't need to use a shell variable for the input file we can use the `awk` variable `FILENAME` instead.

**Demo:**

```
$ cat sourceFile 
PATTERN sf1
sf1
sf1
sf1
PATTERN sf2
sf2
sf2
PATTERN sf3
sf3
sf3

$ awk '/PATTERN/{file="tmp/"(FILENAME)(++i)".txt"}{print > file}' sourceFile

$ cat tmp/sourceFile1.txt
PATTERN sf1
sf1
sf1
sf1

$ cat tmp/sourceFile2.txt 
PATTERN sf2
sf2
sf2

$ cat tmp/sourceFile3.txt 
PATTERN sf3
sf3
sf3
```

Comment: Thank you Sudo - Your solution is closest to what I am looking for I believe but the output location is still a problem:
awk "/PATTERN/{file="my/tmp/dir"(FILENAME)(++i)}{print > file}" srcfile  >> Yeilds this error: awk "/PATTERN/{file="my/tmp/"(FILENAME)(++i)}{print > file}" srcFile
awk: (FILENAME=sourceFile.txt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted....
Thoughts?

Comment: What platform are you on and what version of awk do you have?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.6
Windows 7 - Sorry if you were referring to something else when you referenced platform.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Windows style paths names *(i.e backslashes)* or are you running under cygwin?

Comment: I have tried both - either I get a syntax error on the ":" in C:\directory or the division by zero error. I know it has to be something simple, I am just missing it.

Comment: I have come up with a work-around, and greatly appreciate your help, because you solved my file naming problem - it would still be helpful and aid in my education to fully solve the output location issue.

Comment: @JoshH I'm not familiar with the nuances of `awk` on Windows however did you try double backslashes `"my\\tmp\\dir"` and `C:\\directory\\ `?

Comment: I have not tried this yet - I wasn't aware that it would make a difference. I will try this out and report back

Answer (score 2):

awk could accept shell variables, if you want to set dir and Filename:

```
D="/path/to/newfiles/"
F="sourceFile"

awk -v d="$D" -v f="$F" '/PATTERN/{x=d f (++i)}{print > x;}' sourceFile
```

now, the target dir and filename are dynamic, you could set them to proper values  before the awk call.

yet there is another thing you should pay attention to. how many `PATTERN` in your file. if there are too many, you will see error message something like "too many files opened". in this case, you have to close the last file before writing to new one.