# AWK split files into smaller files on pattern

Tags: loops, awk

I have a file similar to:

```
ISA.00. <rest of line>
information lines
information lines
...
...
...
ISA.00. <rest of line>
information lines
information lines
...
...
ISA.00. <rest of line>
```

I am using:

```
awk "/ISA.00./{file=(FILENAME)(++i)}{print > file}" %LOCATION%\%CURRFILE%
```

To loop through a folder of files, splitting them into files containing one "ISA" data set only. I want to keep the original source file name and add 1 to the end like subfile1, subfile2, subfile3. I have accomplished both.

How would I define an output directory, where the "subfiles" would go, leaving the original source file in the original location, and only having the "subfiles" in the "subfile directory".

I have run into a variety of dead ends and am asking for help as a last resort.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I take it you're on Windows?

Comment: get cygwin and run the UNIX tools from that. save yourself a ton of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory name before the filename:

```
print > "subfiles/"file
```

If you are on windows, you should use the backslash `\` to separate the directory, like this:

```
print > "subfiles\\"file
```

(The backslash should be escaped)

This assumes that the directory already exists. Also, use single quotes when with awk, like `awk 'commands'` file